# Maximum total distance between points on a sphere

Tags: geometry, optimization

What is the configuration (set of locations) of $n$ points on the surface of a sphere such that the **sum of distances** is **maximum** for $n=1,2,3,...$?

The sum of distances is measured by summing the lengths of every straight line (through the sphere) connecting every possible combination of $2$ points. 
All the points are on a single sphere of radius $R$.

Here's a visualization:
[image]

Acknowledgements: Based on [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35353/sum-total-distance-of-electrons-on-a-spherical-surface) Physics S.E. question. Image from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700879/how-to-plot-n-points-on-the-surface-of-a-d-dimensional-sphere-roughly-equidistan).

Comment: Mean distance between 2 points within a sphere http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167932/mean-distance-between-2-points-within-a-sphere might help

Comment: I seem to recall hearing that the problem of maximizing the minimum is unsolved.  But maximizing the sum is another matter.

Comment: A [bunch](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/66365/856) of [previous](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/165819/856) questions [are](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/31619/856) closely [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/9846/856). None is an exact duplicate of this one, but you may find the answers and references there of interest.

Comment: "Straight line"? Through the sphere or on the surface?

Comment: Straight line through the sphere.

Comment: Are you looking for an analytical expression of the configuration or a numerical solution? This is a nonconvex optimization problem and I suspect it has several local solutions that are not global maximizers.

Comment: analytical, I just want to understand the steps involved in solving   the problem

Comment: You may be able to find an analytical expression if you measure geodesic distance (on the surface of the sphere) and use spherical coordinates. This is just a suggestion that could put you on track for the harder question you ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know the answer to the general question is unknown. For the computer approach you can look at [this](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://www.ams.org/mcom/1977-31-140/S0025-5718-1977-0478006-1/S0025-5718-1977-0478006-1.pdf&ei=d6bVUtflDKGa4wSx8YCgAg&usg=AFQjCNGLmVnQZqDrmTvNPIsMdyu4A2zmSQ&sig2=p2quFFEGx1BM7PEriC1PIg&bvm=bv.59378465,d.bGE) article by Berman and Hanes. [Here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0937) it is shown that the result for 5 points on the sphere can be found in finite time by computer. Also you can find some interesting references in the introduction part.

Hope, this will help