# I have $n$-points that are on a unit sphere, how can I show using set builder notation that they are as far a way from each other as possible?

Tags: calculus

For example, if I had 2 points, they could be positioned in any way such that they are $pi$ radians away from each other in the x,y-direction, and for 3 points they would be $2\pi/3$ radians apart in the x,y-direction. I'm just having trouble showing this using set builder notation. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to express this in set-builder notation?

Comment: Well if there's any other way of expressing it that's fine, I'm just setting up a model and I'd like it to be defined mathematically as required by the criterion of the essay.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191273/maximum-total-distance-between-points-on-a-sphere)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to *show* this, but easy to *express* this!

You could characterize an extremal configuration ${\bf a}$ of $n$ points on $S^2$ by writing
$${\bf a}\in {\rm argmax}_{\,{\bf x}\in (S^2)^n}\bigl(\min\nolimits_{1\leq i<j\leq n}
\|x_i-x_j\|\bigr)\ .$$
I don't now whether this is more to the point than describing the idea in words.

Comment: The point of the exercise was to write a paper in which everything needed to be written mathematically. I go to a French school and for some reason, my teacher is very strict with this, even though I find it a bit overkill. However, I believe this is the most concise formalisation of the idea. I assume it's just part of his teaching as it get's you to familiarise with complex set building notation. Thank you for taking your time in responding to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Reformatted after a comment by Arnaud Mortier.

Would something like the following do?  $C = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$ is a subset of $S^2$, the ordinary sphere, such that for all $C' = \{x'_1, x'_2, \ldots, x'_n\}$ a subset of $S^2$,

$$
\min_{x, y \in C} d(x, y) \geq \min_{x', y' \in C'} d(x', y')
$$

Comment: Please don't write in a stream of consciousness manner.  $ S^2 $ is not equal to a finite set. Even if everyone knows what you mean, this is giving very bad habits to people who are not mathematically mature yet.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: You know, I tend to prefer $C = {x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\} \subset S^2$, but for some reason I see that less and see things along the lines of what I have here more.  Do you think the other is preferable?  I'd rather use that.  ETA: I don't know why my comment isn't MathJaxing.

Comment: I don't know either. Anyway, I believe it should be `$\subset $` instead of `$\in $`. And yes, it is better imho. Students who write like this tend to be less able to organise their ideas correctly.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: Oops, yes, I meant `$\subset$` in my comment, not `$\in$`—edited.

Comment: one of several similar problems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tammes_problem

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the set of points on the unit circle. Let $\mathbb P(A)$ be the Power Set (set of all subsets) of $A$. Let $\mathbb P_n(A)$ be defined as $$\{a\in\mathbb P(A)\; |\; |A| = n\}$$

Define $S'\subset\mathbb P_n(S^2)$ such that $$\{Q\in P_n(S)\;|\;\exists\epsilon\;\forall\;i,j\in Q\;i\neq j,\;d(i,j)=\epsilon\}$$

In layman's terms, $S'$ is the set of all sets of $n$ points on the circle such that the distance between any two of them is constant.

Define the function $F$ on elements of $\mathbb P(A)$ to be

$$F(s) = max\{d(i,j)\;|\;i,j\in s\}$$

So, the points you want will be those such that

$$\{s\in S'\;|\;F(s) = \sup\{F(s)\;|\;s\in S'\}\}$$