# Do $4$ balanced points on a sphere form a tetrahedron or lie on a plane?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, symmetry, combinatorial-geometry, spherical-geometry

Let $\mathbb{S}^2$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4 \in \mathbb{S}^2$.

Suppose that $\sum_i x_i=0$, where we sum the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

**Question:** Does one of the following two options hold?

1. The $x_i$ form a regular tetrahedron.
2. The $x_i$ lie on a great circle in $\mathbb{S}^2$. (In that case, they [must in fact form a rectangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4429982/104576)).

**Motivation:**

"Balanced configurations" $x_i \in \mathbb{S}^2$ satisfying $\sum_i x_i=0$, [coincide with the maximizes of the the total squared distance energy](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4429617/104576)
$$
E(x_i)=\sum_{i < j}\| x_i - x_j \|^2,
$$
where $\| x_i - x_j \|$ denotes the Euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

---

It turns out that the set of such balanced configurations form a $5$-dimensional submanifold of $(\mathbb{S}^2)^4$, as it is the inverse image of the regular value zero, of the map $(x_i) \to \sum_i x_i$.

Comment: From $x_i$s that forms a regular tetrahedron, rotate $x_1$ and $x_2$ about the line joining their midpoint and the origin, and the sum of $x_i$s should not change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider these four points:

$$
(0.8,0.6,0) \\
(0.8,-0.6,0) \\
(-0.8,0,0.6) \\
(-0.8,0,-0.6)
$$

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate on how did you come up with this example? Was there some process of producing it? (like in  
peterwhy's comment).

Comment: I took a rectangle and rotated two adjacent vertices around the axis through their midpoint.