# Generating evenly distributed points on a sphere

Tags: algorithms, euclidean-geometry, spherical-geometry, spherical-coordinates, tiling

How could I write an algorithm to generate *n* points distributed 'evenly' on a sphere?  I already wrote an algorithm to generate points distributed uniformly on the surface ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14805715/674039)), but by 'evenly' distributed I mean the way a bunch of electric charges might settle on the surface of a sphere, i.e. **the minimum distance between any pair of points should be maximised**.  For n=2, it would just return any pair of polar opposite points.  For n=32 it would probably look something like a soccerball tiling.  For something general like n=7, I have no idea what it would look like although the problem still seems to me to be well-defined.

Is the problem equivalent whether the distance is measured on the surface or in the 3d space?

Comment: Many related questions here, e.g., http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66365/optimal-distribution-of-points-over-the-surface-of-a-sphere? and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165819/how-to-tile-a-sphere-with-points-at-an-even-density? where several more pointers are given.

Comment: lots of food for thought .. so is the general case an unsolved problem, then?

Comment: That's my impression. I haven't checked to see whether any of the links on this site mention http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/index/spheres.html which has many links that may be of interest

Comment: There are only a few regular solids (i.e., points separated by fixed distances on the sphere).

Comment: [The user presently known as ℝⁿ.](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/856/) has a list of questions on this topic in his profile.

Comment: Sounds to me like putting a bunch of charges on a sphere and running a generic optimization algorithm to minimize potential energy would do a decent job.